# How to make circles in qtree tikz (specifically root)

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I am trying to make trees with `tikz-qtree`. I want every node that "splits" to be a black circle, specifically I want the root to be one. I don't find how am I able to do that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10mm, level distance=10mm, ->,
                    every node/.append style={midway},
                    every circle node/.append style={fill=black}]

\node (Source) [circle] {}
child {node (He) {He} edge from parent node[left] {\scriptsize A}
}
child {node (gave) {gve} edge from parent node[right] {\scriptsize A}}
child {node (an apple) [circle] {}
    {
        child {node (an) {an} edge from parent node[left] {\scriptsize E}}
        child {node (apple){apple} edge from parent node[right] {\scriptsize C}}
    } edge from parent node[right] {\scriptsize P} }
;
                        \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what I have with the package

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10mm, level distance=10mm, ->,
            every node/.append style={midway},
            every circle node/.append style={fill=black}]
            \Tree [
            \edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize A}; He
            \edge node[auto=left]{\scriptsize P}; gave
            \edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize A};
            [
            \edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize A}; an
            \edge node[auto=left]{\scriptsize P}; apple
            ]]
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

These are the circles I want
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple version with Forest, which allows you to just say 'every node with 2 or more children is a filled circle':

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  before typesetting nodes={
    where content={}{coordinate}{},
    where n children>=2{circle, fill}{},
  },
  /tikz/my label look/.style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    pos=.6,
    inner sep=1pt,
    fill=white,
  },
  my label/.style={
    if={
      >Ow+P{n}{isodd(##1)}
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south east] {#1}}
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south west] {#1}}
    }
  },
  for tree={
    edge+={->},
    l'+=7.5pt,
  }
  [
    [He, my label=A]
    [gave, my label=P]
    [, my label=A
      [an, my label=E][apple, my label=C]
    ]
    [, my label=A
      [to, my label=R][John, my label=C]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version]

## EDIT

Here's a `circles at splits` style in case you want the same style for multiple trees. The `my label` style is independent and can, therefore, be used in other kinds of trees, too, if desired.

```
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409170/ addaswyd o ateb borgr: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408920/
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  circles at splits/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={
      where content={}{coordinate}{},
      where n children>=2{circle, fill}{},
    },
    for tree={
      edge+={->},
      l'+=7.5pt,
    },
  },
  /tikz/my label look/.style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    pos=.6,
    inner sep=1pt,
    fill=white,
  },
  my label/.style={
    if={
      >Ow+P{n}{isodd(##1)}
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south east] {#1}}
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south west] {#1}}
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  circles at splits
  [
    [He, my label=A]
    [gave, my label=P]
    [, my label=A
      [an, my label=E][apple, my label=C]
    ]
    [, my label=A
      [to, my label=R][John, my label=C]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Here's a bit of explanation of the style, as requested in comments. For further details, see Forest's manual.

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
```

`linguistics` installs some defaults generally suitable for trees in linguistics, but also for some other kinds of trees. This affects the way that the edges join, for example. Try removing this option and recompiling to see the difference. Although not used here, this option also provides various non-standard styles e.g. `nice empty nodes`, `sn edges` and `roof`.

```
\forestset{%
  circles at splits/.style={%
```

Create a style `circles at splits` which can be applied (or not) to any tree.

```
    before typesetting nodes={
```

This delays the processing of the key's argument until Forest has parsed the tree. Forest works in different 'stages' and this is crucial for certain kinds of customisation. Here, we want to examine the `content` of the nodes before the nodes are typeset, but after their content has been parsed.

```
      where content={}{coordinate}{},
```

This works through the tree and, where nodes have no content, the shape is set to `coordinate`. Where they have content, nothing is done. This avoids ugly gaps when nodes are empty.

```
      where n children>=2{circle, fill}{},
```

This works through the tree and looks for all nodes with at least 2 children. In just these cases, the options `circle, fill` are used, which will be passed to Ti*k*Z as they are not recognised as Forest keys.

```
    },
```

End of delayed processing.

```
    for tree={
      edge+={->},
      l'+=7.5pt,
    },
```

`for tree` works through all nodes of the tree. For every node, `->` is added to the options applied to the node's `edge` (i.e. the line from the parent) and the level distance is increased by 7.5pt. (The actual distance between levels depends on a variety of factors and `l` has different effects depending on the Forest stage in which it is executed. But this will do for our purposes - it stretches out the tree vertically and spaces things out a bit. This avoids our edge labels being too crowded.) When the content of nodes is very small or zero, but there are labels on the edges or around the nodes, it is usually necessary to adjust the spacing, as Forest does not automatically account for space taken by labels.

```
  },
```

End of `circles at splits` style.

```
  /tikz/my label look/.style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    pos=.6,
    inner sep=1pt,
    fill=white,
  },
```

This is just a standard Ti*k*Z style with the usual options.

```
  my label/.style={
```

Another Forest style. This is intended for application to particular nodes, rather than whole trees. It expects a single argument, which will become a label on the node's edge.

```
    if={
      >Ow+P{n}{isodd(##1)}
```

This checks if the node is an odd-numbered child or an even-numbered child.

```
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south east] {#1}}
```

If it is odd-numbered, we set the anchor to `south east`, so the label will go left. We also apply the `my label look` Ti*k*Z style. The argument becomes the content of the label on the edge.

```
    }{
      edge label={node [my label look, anchor=south west] {#1}}
```

Similarly, if the node is even-numbered, except that the anchor is set to `south west`, so that the label will go right.

```
    }
  },
}
```

That's it and we're done.

Comment: Wow, that is great, could you elaborate a bit on what you did in each part (or where to get this syntax from) so people (including me) would have the ability to create such code and not only to copy paste yours with minor changes of parameters?

Comment: @borgr Please see edit above.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it, here is how for others wishing to do something similar. basically what was needed is to add the node with "." after opening with "[" the relevant split.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10mm, level distance=10mm, ->,
                    every node/.append style={midway},
                    every circle node/.append style={fill=black}]
\Tree [.\node [circle] (rootu) {};
\edge node [auto=right]{\scriptsize A}; \node (Heu) {He};
\edge node[auto=right down]{\scriptsize P}; \node (gve) {gve};
\edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize A};
[.\node [circle](an appleu) {};
\edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize E}; \node (anu) {an};
\edge node[auto=left]{\scriptsize C}; \node (appleu) {apple};
]
\edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize A};
[.\node [circle](for john) {};
\edge node[auto=right]{\scriptsize R};\node (for) {for};
\edge node[auto=left]{\scriptsize C}; \node (john) {john};
]]
                        \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: final tree]